# div making inner div's one below another

Tags: html, css

```css
.right {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: brown;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="temp">
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="left">left</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I remove div with class name "temp" then the right and left div appear at right and left corner of the screen.

But if I keep the div "temp" then the right and left div appear one below another.'

[keeping div temp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFxoI.png)

[removing div temp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOBrk.png)

Comment: what is your goal ?

Comment: What do you want to ask? Do note that setting flex to container will impact layout of its immediate child, not grandchilds. So adding temp will change the layout, because then there is only one child of container, left and  right are child of temp div which will have default display property set as block.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
   display: flex;
   background-color: brown;
   justify-content: space-between;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

**Right div and Left div Come in Onebelow another. Like Column**. Try this it will work

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it!

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
    background-color: brown;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.container div {width:100px; height:100px;}
.left{background-color: yellow;}
.right{background-color: yellowgreen;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="left">left</div>
   <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give `flex` to `.temp` not `.container`.

```css
.right {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.left {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.temp{
  display: flex;
  background-color: brown;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="temp">
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="left">left</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currect, here `container` is not effect because the child element of `container` is `temp`. So, in this case it is not working.

```css
.temp {
    display: flex;
    background-color: brown;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.right {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.left {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="temp">
          <div class="right">right</div>
          <div class="left">left</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```